# Was ist "der _äußere_ Ablauf einer Sache"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, duden

Im Duden steht als Bedeutung von "prozedural"

> [verfahrensmäßig; den äußeren Ablauf einer Sache betreffend](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/prozedural)

Was ist der *äußere* Ablauf einer Sache? Gibt es auch den *inneren* Ablauf einer *Sache?* Wenn innere Abläufe *mentale* Abläufe sind, sind dann äußere Abläufe Verhalten?

Falls die Interpretation stimmt, warum der Bezug zum Menschen bzw. zu Lebewesen? Die inneren Abläufe von Maschinen (z.B. Computern) sind doch offensichtlich prozedural.

Answer (score 5):

[Prozedur](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Prozedur) heißt *formaler Ablauf*, *Verfahren*.

*Prozedural* lässt sich synonym zu *[verfahrensmäßig](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verfahrensm%C3%A4%C3%9Fig)* benutzen. Der äußere Ablauf eines Strafprozesses ist beispielsweise durch die Strafprozessordnung geregelt. Dem gegenüber steht der inhaltliche Ablauf, der beispielsweise durch Zeugenaussagen und Einlassungen des Beklagten beeinflusst wird.

Deiner Interpretation bezüglich mentaler und physikalischer Prozesse (beobachtbares Verhalten) stimme ich insoweit zu, als man sie als innere und äußere Abläufe bezeichnen könnte. Allerdings halte ich es für fraglich, ob solche Abläufe als *prozedural* bezeichnet werden können, weil mir *formal* bezüglich mentaler Prozesse zu weit hergeholt erscheint.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1) Ich gehe davon aus, dass mentale Phänomene innerhalb der physikalischen Welt kausal wirksam sind und Verhalten daher nie rein formal sein kann.</sub>

Comment: Vielen Dank für Deine Antwort! Ich verstehe Deine Kritik bzgl. mentaler Prozesse. Aber kannst Du mir vielleicht mit einem Beispiel für "äußere" und "innere" Prozesse helfen, das nicht aus der Rechtsprechung kommt, um deren Unterschied besser zu fassen zu bekommen?

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke, *äußerer Ablauf* bezieht sich auf direkt beobachtbaren Ereignisse, also **was** der Reihe nach passiert ist. Die inneren Abläufe sind demgegenüber die Emotionen, Intentionen, Motivation der Beteiligten, die zu diesen Handlungen und Ereignissen geführt haben.

Wie so soft lohnt sich ein Blick in die Korpora von [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=zeit&q=%C3%A4u%C3%9Ferer%20Ablauf) für mehr Beispiele.

Comment: Hallo und vielen Dank für Deine Antwort! Würdest Du dann auch sagen, dass automatische Prozesse ohne menschliche Beteiligung gar keine inneren Abläufe haben?

Comment: @wehnsdaefflae: Das hängt vom Kontext ab. Man kann beobachten, dass ein Ventil geschlossen wird (äußerer Ablauf); bei welcher Kombination von Druck, Temperatur etc. das passiert, ist vielleicht Teil eines Steuerungsalgorithmus, den man als inneren Ablauf betrachten kann.