# Kann jemand diese Benutzung von "häufiger" erklären?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, comparative

Folgendes habe ich in dem Spiegel gelesen:

> In einem niedersächsischen Corona-Impfzentrum zog eine
> Krankenschwester Spritzen mit Kochsalz auf. Das genaue Ausmaß ist
> unklar, doch die Ermittler sind überzeugt: Die Frau handelte häufiger
> so.

Warum benutzt die Zeitschrift im letzten Satz das Wort "häufiger" statt einfach "häufig"?  Es gibt da keinen anscheinenden Vergleich, deshalb vermute ich, dass "häufiger" in einem anderen Sinn als einem Vergleich verwendet wird.

Comment: Auf Englisch: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/11884/35111

Comment: @DavidVogt: Danke für den Link.  Wir haben natürlich auch in der englischen Sprache diesen "absoluten Komparativ": an older gentleman, a more expensive hotel, usw.  Mir war aber nicht eingefallen, dass eine solche Benutzung von "häufiger" in die gleiche Kategorie gehört.  Mir scheint, dass die deutsche Version mehr Vagheit als die englische im impliziten Vergleich erlaubt.

Comment: Ein weitere englische [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/63048/1696) zum gleichen Thema.

Comment: @guidot: Danke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Man könnte sagen, "häufiger" hat hier einen impliziten Vergleich. Wenn man in dieser Form "häufiger" statt "häufig" verwendet, impliziert das etwas wie "häufiger als bisher bekannt", "häufiger als viele Leute denken", "häufiger als es üblich ist" oder etwas ähnliches.

Und in dem [zitierten Artikel](https://www.spiegel.de/panorama/justiz/corona-im-landkreis-friesland-kochsalzloesung-statt-biontech-tausende-sollen-nachgeimpft-werden-a-8842b2b4-065a-479c-8ba6-72d0419a03f6) geht es tatsächlich darum, dass die Krankenschwester *häufiger* Kochsalzlösung anstatt Impfstoff gespritzt haben soll *als bisher bekannt*:

> Im April hatte die Frau **sechs Fälle** eingeräumt – angeblich die Folge eines Missgeschicks, weil ihr beim Anmischen eine Ampulle zu Boden gefallen sei, was sie habe vertuschen wollen. Doch an dieser Version gibt es Zweifel. Die Behörden im Landkreis Friesland gehen inzwischen davon aus, dass **mehr als 8500 Menschen** unfreiwillig keinen oder nur einen teilweisen Impfschutz bekommen haben könnten.

(Hervorhebungen von mir)

Comment: Danke. Ich glaube, das erklärt es.

Answer (score -2):

Man könnte das als imperfektes partizip verstehen. Im Slavischen, Friechischen und bspw. Türkisch gibt es imperfekte Verbformen, die gewohnheit beschreiben, also sich wiederholende Vorgänge. So kann das auch hier bes-ser verstanden werden, was nicht heißen soll das Henning Kockerbeck sei Antwort schlecht oder gar falsch wäre.

Es gibt auch ein schönes Gegenbeispiel für einen scheinbaren Superlativ ohne vereich: *einzigster*. Das wird zwar zu hauf als falschdeutsch bezeichnet, aber diejenigen haben halt keine Ahnung von Tun und Belassen.

So ist auch *öfters* bekannt, das über die reine Steigerungsform hinaus eine Ahndung ähnlich *-wärts* für Amadverbialen Gebrauch erhält. Partizien zählen manchermal mithin zu Adverben.

Ob es sich dabei um Überreste des sigmatischen-Aorists, der oben mit Hinweis auf die anderen Fremdsprachen angedeutet wurde, inklusive Rhotazismus (r < *z < *s) handelte mag ggf. dahinstehen.

PS: Siehe ebenger ade nebenan noch [äußerer Ablauf](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/65879/was-ist-der-%c3%a4u%c3%9fere-ablauf-einer-sache). Das ist ebenso kein Komparativ, wohl aber als Kontradtiv zu verstehen.